# BeanCreationException NoSuchBeanDefinitionException using Spring roo

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo, bean-validation

I am getting an exception thrown when i attempt to access my service, i used spring roo to create my spring data jpa repository which generated the file `applicationContext-jpa.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="org.bixin.dugsi" />

</beans:beans>
```

My applicationContext.xml is in the same directory `META-INF/spring/` and i have made sure to include the component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.bixin.dugsi">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

The test use case in how i am using it, is below:

```
@RooIntegrationTest(entity = UserAccount.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
public class UserAccountIntegrationTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {


    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "persistenceUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory factory;
    PasswordService testsPasswordService = new CustomPasswordService();

    @Autowired
    private AccountSettingsRepository accountSettingsRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Test
    public void testAccount(){

        accountService.saveAccountSettings(accountSettings);
        Assert.assertNotNull(accountSettings);
    }
```

I cant figure out what could be causing this exception, i told it exactly where to find the service implementation and repository. Full stack trace is below:

```
2012-07-01 14:11:06,661 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@512d8ecd] to prepare test instance [org.bixin.dugsi.domain.UserAccountIntegrationTest@97d01f]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.bixin.dugsi.repositories.AccountSettingsRepository org.bixin.dugsi.service.AccountServiceImpl.accountSettingsRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.bixin.dugsi.repositories.AccountSettingsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.bixin.dugsi.repositories.AccountSettingsRepository org.bixin.dugsi.service.AccountServiceImpl.accountSettingsRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.bixin.dugsi.repositories.AccountSettingsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.bixin.dugsi.repositories.AccountSettingsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 41 more
2012-07-01 14:11:06,666 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [[TestContext@1ebcda2d testClass = UserAccountIntegrationTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@6ee0a386 testClass = UserAccountIntegrationTest, locations = '{classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

The account settings repository

package org.bixin.dugsi.repositories;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.bixin.dugsi.domain.AccountSettings;
import org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.jpa.RooJpaRepository;

@RooJpaRepository(domainType = AccountSettings.class)
public interface AccountSettingsRepository {

}
```

Context applicationContext-Jpa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="org.bixin.dugsi.repositories" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Please show the `org.bixin.dugsi.repositories.AccountSettingsRepository` source code.

Comment: updated to show this repository, component scan wont pick it up

Comment: Just for test, try commenting your context exclude filters.

Comment: commented both filters out from applicationContext.xml, same error with beans not being created. I might be missing some bean definitions in the roo created applicationContext-jpa.xml file. I have just posted that

Comment: Is your applicationContext-jpa.xml file properly imported in your main context file ?

Comment: not sure where i would check for that in my main context file? Is there a headers section

Comment: maybe something like `<import resource="applicationContext-jpa.xml"/>`

Comment: Great man, that import did it, i ended up placing it in the right place under the bean declaration. I seem to get my record saved and test passes. Put it in an answer to give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your `applicationContext-jpa.xml` is loaded by your main context.

To do that, check that your `applicationContext.xml` contains:

```
<import resource="applicationContext-jpa.xml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading the applicationContext-jpa.xml in your test. Modify the locations attribute within the ContextConfiguration annotation of the UserAccounIntegrationTest.

You'd better let Roo to create the tests with "-testAutomatically" in the "entity" command or using the command "integration test".

Roo will create the appropriate location using a wildcard: "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml" in an AspectJ file (.aj) for the integration test.

NOTE: if you want to add your own applicationContex-test.xml in the test/resources folder, you need to modify the locations by adding a '*' after classpath: "classpath*:..."